# BarCode Maker (pulling data from other sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a function that will construct a bar code from a few data points within my spreadsheet for items in an inventory.

My issue/question is two fold:

1. When running through the `for loop`, I am getting this error message `"TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null."`
2. While it looks like I have successfully loaded the ranges I want into veritable, I am not entirely sure as to how to call them, could you please tell me if I am calling them correctly within the `if` statement?

---

```
function barCodeBuilder(stockName) {

  // Setting Ranges from prices table
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var listNameRange = sheet.getRangeByName('MeterailsPricing!ITEM NAME');
  var listSkuRange = sheet.getRangeByName('MeterailsPricing!INVENTORY SKU');
  var listPriceRange = sheet.getRangeByName('MeterailsPricing!PRICE');
  var listSupRange = sheet.getRangeByName('MeterailsPricing!SUPPLIER CODE');

  //Errors begin here = TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null
  for(listCounter = 0; listCounter < listNameRange.length; listCounter++){
    if(stockName == listNameRange[listCounter][0]){
      var barCode = {
        sku:listSkuRange[listCounter][0],
        supCode:listSupRange[listCounter][0],
        price:listPriceRange[listCounter][0]};
    }
  }

  //final bar code assembly
  var finalBarCode = barCode.sku + "-" + barCode.supCode + "-" + barCode.price;
  return finalBarCode;
}
```

And as always, thank you all for taking the time to help me out.

Talk to you soon.
Greg R.

Answer (score 0):

Error **"TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null."** occurred if there were no matches for the regular expression. Because of this, `listNameRange` will be null. You need to check for this before your loop.

Sample code snippet from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12949783/5832311):

> ```
> if (templateVars !== null) {
>     for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; i++) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Here are some related SO posts which might help:

- [TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949618/typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-from-null)
- [Google Spreadsheets script to delete any rows where a string is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462125/google-spreadsheets-script-to-delete-any-rows-where-a-string-is-found)